# Odoo Customer invoicing address in all pages

Tags: odoo-10

Is there any way I could pull customer's address/shipping address to top of all the pages of invoice?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you need to call it in the invoice header. What did you try yet?

Comment: Kindly give minimal code what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it on the invoice header or footer. Both are shown in all pages.

```
 <div class="header"> 
   <div class="row"> 
      <div name="invoice_address" class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-7">
         <address t-field="o.partner_id" t-options='{"widget": "contact", "fields": ["address", "name"], "no_marker": True}' /> 
         <span t-if="o.partner_id.vat">TIN: 
         <span t-field="o.partner_id.vat"/></span> 
      </div> 
  </div>
```

Comment: Kindly explain what are you trying to say. It's not at all understandable.